# Replace with non-commutative product

Tags: replacement, rule, operators

I'm trying to evaluate some scattering amplitudes terms in Mathematica using the spinor helicity formalism. For that, I need to turn products like $\epsilon_i\cdot k_j$ into spinor product which can be evaluated numerically. In order to do that, I'm using simple replacement rules in a function called `subsp` that has worked so far. However, now I'm encountering the following terms:
$$
\epsilon_i\cdot f_j\cdot f_k\cdot ...\cdot f_l \cdot \epsilon_p,
$$

where the $f$ are defined as an outer product: $f_i^{\mu\nu}=k_i^\mu\epsilon_i^\nu-\epsilon_i^\mu k_i^\nu$. Regarding the code, my program firstly returns the terms like this: `epsilon[i,poli].f[j,polj].f[k,polk].epsilon[l,poll]` for example, where the different `pol` just indicate the polarization for each particle. Now, if I had products like $\epsilon_i\cdot k_j$, I would just make replacements like

`epsilon[a_, P].k[b_Integer] -> epsPk[a, b, q_a]`,

where `epsPk[a, b, q_a]` is a function that knows how to evaluate such product with spinors (the P just indicates positive polarization). For the $f$, I tried doing

`f[i_, poli_] :> k[i]epsilon[i,poli]-epsilon[i,poli]k[i]`,

but obviously this evaluates to zero. I also tried replacing products like $\epsilon_i\cdot f_j$ with

`epsilon[i_, poli_].f[j_, polj_] -> epsilon[i, poli].k[j]*epsilon[j, polj] - epsilon[i, poli].epsilon[j, polj]*k[j]`,

but this also doesn't work. The problem is that longer chains get blocked by the priority of `Times` over `Dot` (I think that's what the problem is). For example, if I type:

`subsp[epsilon[3, p].f[2, p].k[4]]`

I get the following output:

`-(k[2]spb[2, 3]).k[4]/spa[3, 2] + Sqrt[2] (epsilon[2, p]spa[4, 2]spb[2, 3]).k[4]/spa[4, 3]`

As you can see, the function has succesfully contracted `epsilon[3,p]` with the fisrt half of `f[2,p]` (notice the spinor terms like `spa[3, 2]` or `spb[2, 3]`), but fails to do so with the right half of `f[2,p]` and `k[4]` because it is blocked by the parenthesis (more precisely, I would need it to further contract `k[2].k[4]` in the negative term and `epsilon[2,p].k[2]` in the positive one).

In conclusion, I need to be able to successfully define either a non-vanishing `f[i,poli]` or an arbitrarily long chain of products `epsilon[i,poli].f[j,polj].`...`.f[k,polk].epsilon[l,poll]` with the replacement rules. If anyone could help me with this issue, I would reall appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've been requested to provide more insight into what my code looks like and what I'm aiming. What I'm trying to calculate specifically are something called BCJ numerators, which I obtain from a set of tree diagrams with another function that isn't important to this issue. One possible output that can serve as the starting point to illustrate the problem is:

`epsilon[3,p].epsilon[5,m] k[3].k[{1,2}]epsilon[1,p].f[3,p].epsilon[5,m]`

The only new thing apart from what I've already explained are lists being arguments of `k`. This represents a sum of momenta, e.g. `k[{1,2}]=k[1]+k[2]` (which I've succesfully implemented in the function below). I would like to keep this output format intact. Now, I want `subsp` to convert this into a product of spinor functions `spa` and `spb`. This is howI do it:

`subsp[expr_, n_] := Module[{a, b, c, pol, pola, polb}, rules = {s[a_, b_] -> spa[a, b]*spb[b, a], epsPP[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] -> spa[qa, qb]*spb[b, a]/(spa[qa, a]*spa[qb, b]), epsPM[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] -> spa[qa, b]*spb[qb, a]/(spa[qa, a]*spb[qb, b]), epsMP[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] -> spb[qa, b]*spa[qb, a]/(spb[qa, a]*spa[qb, b]), epsMM[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] -> spb[qa, qb]*spa[b, a]/(spb[qa, a]*spb[qb, b]), epsPk[a_, b_, qa_] -> Sqrt[2]*spa[qa, b]*spb[b, a]/spa[qa, a], epsMk[a_, b_, qa_] -> Sqrt[2]*spb[qa, b]*spa[b, a]/spb[qa, a], epsilon[b_, pol_].k[a : _List] :> TensorExpand[epsilon[b, pol].Total[ Map[k, a]]], epsilon[a_, p].epsilon[b_, p] -> epsPP[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1], Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], epsilon[a_, p].epsilon[b_, m] -> epsPM[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1], Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], epsilon[a_, m].epsilon[b_, p] -> epsMP[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1], Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], epsilon[a_, m].epsilon[b_, m] -> epsMM[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1] + 1, Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], epsilon[a_, p].k[b_Integer] -> epsPk[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1]], epsilon[a_, m].k[b_Integer] -> epsMk[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1]], k[a_Integer]. k[b_List] :> TensorExpand[k[a].Total[Map[k, b]]], k[a_Integer].k[b_Integer] -> 1/2*s[a, b], f[b_, polb_] :> k[b] ** epsilon[b, polb] - epsilon[b, polb] ** k[b], expf[a_] -> 1 + a};expr2 = FixedPoint[Expand[TensorExpand[ReplaceRepeated[#, rules]]] &, expr]];`

I know this has some inefficient definitions like the redundant intermediate functions `epsPP` or `epskM`, but they are there because they are useful in some other applications. Using this function, the DESIRED output of the previous example would be:

```
(Sqrt[2] spa[3, 5] spa[4, 5] spb[6, 3]^2)/(spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5]^2) - (Sqrt[2] spa[2, 4] spa[3, 5] spb[3, 1] spb[6, 3])/(spa[2, 1] spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5])`,
```

but the problem I mentioned with the `f` functions instead gives me:

```
-((epsilon[1, p].epsilon[3, p] ** k[3].epsilon[5, m] spa[1, 3] spa[4,5] spb[3, 1] spb[6, 3])/(2 spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5])) + (epsilon[1, p].k[3] ** epsilon[3, p].epsilon[5, m] spa[1, 3] spa[4,5] spb[3, 1] spb[6, 3])/(2 spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5]) - (epsilon[1, p].epsilon[3, p] ** k[3].epsilon[5, m] spa[2, 3] spa[4, 5] spb[3, 2] spb[6, 3])/(2 spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5]) + (epsilon[1, p].k[3] ** epsilon[3, p].epsilon[5, m] spa[2, 3] spa[4, 5] spb[3, 2] spb[6, 3])/(2 spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5])
```

i.e. there are still `epsilon` and `k` functions to be contracted.

Comment: I'd suggest `NonCommutativeMultiply` (`**`) for your products - as the name suggests, it's not commutative, and it also doesn't have any built-in meaning that would lead to unwanted evaluation

Comment: I tried that. However, the problem persists: `NonCommutativeMultiply` has priority with respect to `Dot` so, even after `TensorExpand`, the output looks like                `-epsilon[3, p].epsilon[2, p] ** k[2].k[4] + epsilon[3, p].k[2] ** epsilon[2, p].k[4]`, with no further evaluation

Comment: Can you please provide a fully working sample of your current code with the current & the desired output? E.g. you mention `subsp`, but it's not clear how it is defined

Comment: @LukasLang I've added more details in the post and provided an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet a complete answer, but I hope it's a start: It manages to contract all the `epsilon` factors, but the result is not what you mention as expected output. Unfortunately, I don't understand your notation enough to tell where the problem lies.

```
subsp[expr_, n_] := 
  Module[{rules}, 
   rules = {s[a_, b_] :> spa[a, b]*spb[b, a], 
     epsPP[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] :> 
      spa[qa, qb]*spb[b, a]/(spa[qa, a]*spa[qb, b]), 
     epsPM[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] :> 
      spa[qa, b]*spb[qb, a]/(spa[qa, a]*spb[qb, b]), 
     epsMP[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] :> 
      spb[qa, b]*spa[qb, a]/(spb[qa, a]*spa[qb, b]), 
     epsMM[a_, b_, qa_, qb_] :> 
      spb[qa, qb]*spa[b, a]/(spb[qa, a]*spb[qb, b]), 
     epsPk[a_, b_, qa_] :> Sqrt[2]*spa[qa, b]*spb[b, a]/spa[qa, a], 
     epsMk[a_, b_, qa_] :> Sqrt[2]*spb[qa, b]*spa[b, a]/spb[qa, a], 
     epsilon[b_, pol_] ** Dot ** k[a : _List] :> 
      epsilon[b, pol] ** Dot ** Total[Map[k, a]], 
     epsilon[a_, p] ** Dot ** epsilon[b_, p] :> 
      epsPP[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1], Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], 
     epsilon[a_, p] ** Dot ** epsilon[b_, m] :> 
      epsPM[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1], Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], 
     epsilon[a_, m] ** Dot ** epsilon[b_, p] :> 
      epsMP[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1], Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], 
     epsilon[a_, m] ** Dot ** epsilon[b_, m] :> 
      epsMM[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1] + 1, Mod[b + 1, n, 1]], 
     epsilon[a_, p] ** Dot ** k[b_Integer] :> 
      epsPk[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1]], 
     epsilon[a_, m] ** Dot ** k[b_Integer] :> 
      epsMk[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1]], 
     k[b_Integer] ** Dot ** epsilon[a_, p] :> 
      epsPk[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1]], 
     k[b_Integer] ** Dot ** epsilon[a_, m] :> 
      epsMk[a, b, Mod[a + 1, n, 1]], 
     k[a_Integer] ** Dot ** k[b_List] :> 
      k[a] ** Dot ** Total[Map[k, b]], 
     k[a_Integer] ** Dot ** k[b_Integer] :> 1/2*s[a, b], 
     f[b_, polb_] :> 
      k[b] ** epsilon[b, polb] - epsilon[b, polb] ** k[b], 
     expf[a_] :> Identity + a,
     Identity ** Dot ** a_ | a_  ** Dot ** Identity :> a,
     (m_?NumericQ a_) ** b_ :> a ** b,
     a_ ** (m_?NumericQ b_) :> m a ** b,
     a_ ** (b_ / c_) :> a ** b / c,
     (a_ / c_) ** b_ :> a ** b / c}; 
   FixedPoint[
     ReplaceRepeated[# /. m_NonCommutativeMultiply :> Distribute[m], 
       rules] &, expr] /. {NonCommutativeMultiply -> Times}];

subsp[
   epsilon[3, p] ** Dot ** epsilon[5, m] ** k[3] ** Dot ** k[{1, 2}] **
     epsilon[1, p] ** Dot ** f[3, p] ** Dot ** epsilon[5, m], 100] // FullSimplify
(* (spa[4, 
    5] (-spa[2, 4] spa[3, 5] + 
     spa[2, 3] spa[4, 5]) (spa[3, 1] spb[1, 3] + 
     spa[3, 2] spb[2, 3]) spb[3, 1] spb[6, 3]^2)/(Sqrt[2]
    spa[2, 1] spa[4, 3]^2 spb[6, 5]^2) *)

subsp[
    epsilon[1, p] ** Dot ** f[3, p] ** Dot ** epsilon[5, m], 100] // FullSimplify // Expand
(* -((Sqrt[2] spa[2, 4] spa[3, 5] spb[3, 1] spb[6, 3])/(
  spa[2, 1] spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5])) + (
 Sqrt[2] spa[2, 3] spa[4, 5] spb[3, 1] spb[6, 3])/(
 spa[2, 1] spa[4, 3] spb[6, 5]) *)
```

The changes I made:

- Made proper use of `Module` to localize `rules` instead of the (already localized) pattern names
- Replaced everything with `RuleDelayed` to help the syntax highlighter
- Replaced all relevant products with `**`. The products that indicate dot products are written as `a**Dot**b`. This prevents any issues with incorrect grouping between e.g. `.` and `**` products that you have seen (thanks to the [`Flat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) attribute of `**`) while still allowing us to distinguish "normal" products from dot products.
- I added rules for `k**Dot**epsilon` style dot products (these might be wrong, currently they are the same as the corresponding `epsilon**Dot**k` products)
- I removed all the useless `Expand` and `TensorExpand` calls
- I added two rules `(m_?NumericQ a_) ** b_ :> m a ** b, a_ ** (m_?NumericQ b_) :> m a ** b` to factor out numeric prefactors that interfere with the other rules
- Similarly, I added two rules `a_ ** (b_ / c_) :> a ** b / c, (a_ / c_) ** b_ :> a ** b / c` that move denominators to the end of the prosuct, such that they are out of the way of the other rules
- I added a call to [`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html) to distribute the `**` over the `+`.
- I replace `**` with the normal `*` in the last step to allow the final result to properly simplify.
- I replaced the 1 in `expf` with `Identity` to indicate the identity tensor, and added the relevant contration rules

I hope this helps you in some way, even though the result is not yet what you expect (as mentioned).

With all that being said, I am not convinced this is the best route forward: It seems to me that a formalism capturing the indices being contracted (the $\mu$ and $\nu$ in your example) would be way easier. That removes the issues with products that should not commute and automatically gives you the distributive law and factoring out of numeric prefactors etc.

Comment: After some minor tweeking, this definitely works better than what I had, but there are still some problematic cases. For example, if I type this: `subsp[epsilon[2, p]**Dot**k[{1}]**epsilon[3, m]**Dot**k[{1, 2}],4]`, I get this result: `Sqrt[2]((spa[3, 1] spb[1, 2])/spa[3, 2])**epsilon[3, m]**Dot**(k[1] + k[2])`, which is still not completely reduced. It seems like the `Distribute` isn't working as it should.

Comment: @Marcosko I have edited the answer with a fix for the `Distribute` issue. The issue was that the expression was something like `a*(b**c)`, meaning the `Distribute` didn't see the `**`. The new version simply applies `Distribute` manually. As for the other tweaks: In the interest of making the answer fully correct & working, what changes were required? (Please feel free to suggest an edit to the answer if that's easier than describing the fixes in the comments)

Comment: Don't worry too much about the tweeks, they were just to adapt the function to additional stuff I didn't include in the post in order to not complicate things (I probably should have phrased my comment differently). Anyways, there are two remaining problems now: first, the function fails when there are fractions, sine it can't differentiate numerators and denominators faithfully when ussing `**` and `**Dot**`. For example, trying to calculate `subsp[epsilon[1, p]**Dot**(f[2, p]/epsilon[2, p]**Dot**k[{1}])**Dot**(f[3, m]/epsilon[3, m]**Dot**k[{1, 2}])**Dot** epsilon[4, m], 7]` fails.

Comment: @Marcosko what is the intended meaning of the division? The same as for multiplication, but with a 1/epsilon factor?

Comment: The second problem comes from the presence of the exponential `expf` which I expand as `expf[a_] :> 1 + a`. This leads to some terms having things like `**Dot**1**Dot**` with which the function doesn't know how to deal. Have you any idea of how it could be fixed?

Comment: The division is indeed a numerical division by some factors like `epsilon[3,p]**Dot**k[{1,2}]` which need to be contracted to spinor products (they are independent, not contracted with any other stuff).

Comment: @Marcosko can you give concrete examples of input and expected output for both cases? For the `expf` issue: is the 1 the identity tensor? Or is the `a` a number, and the `expf` by extension as well? For the division issue: my initial guess would have been to just leave the division there (if the stuff in the denominator doesn't "interact" with the numerator by means of tensor contraction, this shouldn't cause any issues)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139060/discussion-between-marcosko-and-lukas-lang).

Answer (score 0):

One could define

```
dots[x__,f[b_,polb_],y__]:=( dots[x,k[b]]*dots[epsilon[b,polb],y]
                            -dots[x,epsilon[b,polb]]*dots[k[b],y])//Expand;
```

For example,

```
dots[epsilon[1,p],f[2,p],f[3,m],k[4]]
```

returns

```
dots[epsilon[1,p],k[2]] dots[epsilon[2,p],k[3]] dots[epsilon[3,m],k[4]]
-dots[epsilon[1,p],epsilon[2,p]] dots[epsilon[3,m],k[4]] dots[k[2],k[3]]
-dots[epsilon[1,p],k[2]] dots[epsilon[2,p],epsilon[3,m]] dots[k[3],k[4]]
+dots[epsilon[1,p],epsilon[2,p]] dots[k[2],epsilon[3,m]] dots[k[3],k[4]]
```

which is a sum of products of simple terms of the form `dots[k[_],epsilon[_,_]]` and similar, which can then be rewritten in terms of `spa` and `spb`.

Comment: Yes, but each element `x`, `f`, `y` are not connected in the original output (and it would be very non-trivial to do so), i.e. they can't appear simply as arguments of the `dots` function.